# How can I a nested navigation for my react native app

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have my App stack with Tab navigation and I want to add some more screens to my settings page below is my ***App.js*** page how can I do it
[App.js](https://codeshare.io/PdAyqw)

[image]

I need to add to make a ***SettingsStack*** for this below page

[Settings.js](https://codeshare.io/BAb9YL)

Comment: Did you take a look at react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/  docs? If not this can be helpful.

Comment: yes but got too many errors so i thought i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Create a function (for eg: 'TabNavigation') which returns tab navigator component then try putting tab navigator inside stack like below example

```
import Profile from '../screens/settings/Profile';
import ManageRooms from '../screens/settings/ManageRooms';
....
const TabNavigation = () => {
 <Tab.Navigator 
   .....
 </<Tab.Navigator>
}
....
 <NavigationContainer>
   {authState.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Tabs"
        screenOptions={{
         headerShown: false,
        }}>
       <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabNavigation} />
        <Stack.Screen
          key={'Profile'}
          name={'Profile'}
          component={Profile}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          key={'ManageRooms'}
          name={'ManageRooms'}
          component={ManageRooms}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>) : (
      <Stack.Navigator
         screenOptions={{
            header: () => {},
         }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
   )}
 </NavigationContainer>
....
```